# How to loop rows of a table

Tags: python

I was trying to make a table that shows the temperature in celsius and in fahrenheit, making it go from 0 to 100 celsius and jumping 10 degrees each time. However, when trying to do this I create 10 different tables. Here's the code:

```
def main():
    from tabulate import tabulate
    for i in range(0,110,10):
        celsius = i
        fahrenheit = 9/5 * celsius + 32
        table = [["Celsius", "Fahrenheit"], [celsius, fahrenheit]]
        print(tabulate(table, headers="firstrow", tablefmt='fancy_grid'))

main()
```

Comment: Don't post images or links of code. Provide them as text inside a code block.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You should post the text of your code here, not just links to images. However, it looks to me like you should be gathering your lists into one big list and delivering that to `tabulate` right at the end. You should review the examples of usage on the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) website

Comment: Sorry! Started coding this week and was my first post. How would I do that?

Comment: @quamrana forgot to tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you should start a list off with the header names in it and append further info and call tabulate at the end:

```py
def main():
    from tabulate import tabulate

    table = [["Celsius", "Fahrenheit"]]
    for i in range(0,110,10):
        celsius = i
        fahrenheit = 9/5 * celsius + 32
        row = [celsius, fahrenheit]
        table.append(row)
    print(tabulate(table, headers="firstrow", tablefmt='fancy_grid'))

main()
```

Warning: I've not tested this code. I just looked for examples on pypi.prg

Comment: That totally works! Thank you, I understand what I did wrong :)

Comment: Excellent news. It seems quite rare that answers I give result in the OP understanding the problem.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Mark this answer as the accepted answer if it helped you.